# Using np.apply_along_axis but on on certain indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array, `X`, of shape `(200, 200, 1500)`. I also have a function, `func`, that essentially returns the mean of an array (it does a few other things but they are are all numpy operations, you can think of it as `np.mean`). Now if I want to apply this function across the second array I could just do `np.apply_along_axis(func, 2, X)`. But, I also have a truth array of shape `(200, 200, 1500)`. I want to only apply `func` to places where the truth array has `True`. So it would ignore any places where the truth array is false. So going back to the `np.mean` example it would take the mean for each array index across the second axis but ignore some arbitrary set of indices.

So in practice, my solution would be to convert`X` into a new array `Y` with shape `(200, 200)` but the elements of the array are lists. This would be done using the truth array. Then apply `func` to each list in the array. The problem is this seems very time consuming since and I feel like there is a numpy oriented solution for this. Is there?

If what I said with the array list is the best way, how would I go about combining `X` and the truth array to get `Y`?

Any suggestions or comments appreciated.

Comment: If it is **actual** `np.mean` you could just use a masked array. Depending how you've written your function it might just do the right thing automatically if given a masked array, because the whole point is that most array operations should "just work" with masked arrays, without doing anything special. Or is this question about the general case where `func` cannot be relied on to do the right thing with masked arrays?

Comment: `apply_along_axis` isn't worth fussing with.  If applying it isn't obvious, move on; iterate or better yet do some sort of whole-array/masked operation.

Comment: Anyway, you can construct your masked array as `Y = np.ma.array(X, mask=not your_truth_array)` Then experiment to get a feel for what masked array will do for you. Observe that `np.mean(Y, axis=2)` will "just work" as regards ignoring the masked elements, likewise other array operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [268]: X = np.random.randint(0,100,(200,200,1500))
```

Let's check how `apply` works with just `np.mean`:

```
In [269]: res = np.apply_along_axis(np.mean, 2, X)                                                   
In [270]: res.shape                                                                                  
Out[270]: (200, 200)
In [271]: timeit res = np.apply_along_axis(np.mean, 2, X)                                            
1.2 s ± 36.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

An equivalent using iteration on the first two dimensions.  I'm using `reshape` to make it easier to write; speed should be about the same with a double loop.

```
In [272]: res1 = np.reshape([np.mean(row) for row in X.reshape(-1,1500)],(200,200))                  
In [273]: np.allclose(res, res1)                                                                     
Out[273]: True
In [274]: timeit res1 = np.reshape([np.mean(row) for row in X.reshape(-1,1500)],(200,200))           
906 ms ± 13 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

So `apply` may be convenient, but it is **not** a speed tool.

For speed in `numpy` you need to maximize the use of compiled code, and avoiding unnecessary python level loops.

```
In [275]: res2 = np.mean(X,axis=2)                                                                   
In [276]: np.allclose(res2,res)                                                                      
Out[276]: True
In [277]: timeit res2 = np.mean(X,axis=2)                                                            
120 ms ± 619 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

If using `apply` in your new case is hard, you don't loose anything by using something you do understand.

## masked

```
In [278]: mask = np.random.randint(0,2, X.shape).astype(bool)
```

The [272] iteration can be adapted to work with mask:

```
In [279]: resM1 = np.reshape([np.mean(row[m]) for row,m in zip(X.reshape(-1,1500),mask.reshape(-1,150
     ...: 0))],X.shape[:2])                                                                          
In [280]: timeit resM1 = np.reshape([np.mean(row[m]) for row,m in zip(X.reshape(-1,1500),mask.reshape
     ...: (-1,1500))],X.shape[:2])                                                                   
1.43 s ± 18.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

This might have problems if `row[m]` is empty. `np.mean([])` produces a warning and `nan` value.

Applying the mask to `X` before any further processing looses dimensional information.

```
In [282]: X[mask].shape                                                                              
Out[282]: (30001416,)
```

`apply` only works with one array, so it will be awkward (though not impossible) to use it to iterate on both `X` and `mask`.  A structured array with data and mask fields might do the job.  But the previous timings show, there's no speed advantage.

## masked array

I don't usually expect masked arrays to offer speed, but this case it helps:

```
In [285]: xM = np.ma.masked_array(X, ~mask)                                                          
In [286]: resMM = np.ma.mean(xM, axis=2)                                                             
In [287]: np.allclose(resM1, resMM)                                                                  
Out[287]: True
In [288]: timeit resMM = np.ma.mean(xM, axis=2)                                                      
849 ms ± 20.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

## `np.nanmean`

There's a set of functions that use `np.nan` masking:

```
In [289]: Xfloat = X.astype(float)                                                                   
In [290]: Xfloat[~mask] = np.nan                                                                     
In [291]: resflt = np.nanmean(Xfloat, axis=2)                                                        
In [292]: np.allclose(resM1, resflt)                                                                 
Out[292]: True
In [293]: %%timeit 
     ...: Xfloat = X.astype(float) 
     ...: Xfloat[~mask] = np.nan 
     ...: resflt = np.nanmean(Xfloat, axis=2) 
     ...:  
     ...:                                                                                            
2.17 s ± 200 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

This doesn't help  :(